# Project 'ClassLibraryX.csproj' targets 'netstandard2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a class library project that targets netstandard 2.1 and when I referenced that to my WinForms .NET Framework Project that targets .NET Framework v4.7.2 I get an error on building.

> Project 'ClassLibraryX.csproj' targets 'netstandard2.1'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2

Comment: That's [a fact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), you'll have to target 2.0

Answer (score 0):

@esav96:

.NET Framework doesn't support .NET Standard 2.1. For more information.

You can see [the announcement of .NET Standard 2.1.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#:%7E:text=.NET%20Framework%20doesn%27t%20support%20.NET%20Standard%202.1.%20For%20more%20information%2C%20see%20the%20announcement%20of%20.NET%20Standard%202.1).